# How does dynamic linker work for those stripped binaries?

Tags: dynamic-linking, elf

Since `strip` removes symbol names,how can the dynamic linker still find the desired symbols?

Answer (score 0):

`strip` does not remove all symbols. `nm -D` will show the dynamic symbols, which are not stripped (by default). There are other modes, such as stripping debugging symbols or only leaving those.

Comment: At least symbol names are stripped,right? I don't think dynamic linker can still work without the symbol names...

Comment: Internal ones are, but those resolved by the dynamic linker aren't on the ELF systems I've encountered. Other systems may store those symbols separately, allowing the libraries to not contain them.